# How to redeploy partial tasks without editing and disabling tasks in azure release pipeline

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline

The deployment of the company product has several tasks to finish. For example,

- task 1 to copy some build files to server A
- task 2 to copy some build files to server B

task 1 or 2 could fail and we need to redeploy only the failed task because each task takes a long time to finish.

I can split the tasks into different stages but we have a long tasks list and if we include staging and production it will be difficult to manage.

so my question is

- is there an easy way to redeploy partial tasks without editing and disabling the tasks in the stage?
- or a better way to organize multiple stages into one group like 'Staging' or 'Production' so I can have a better visualization of the release stages

thanks

Update:
Thanks [@jessehouwing](https://stackoverflow.com/users/736079/jessehouwing)
Found there is an option when I click redeploy. See screenshot below.
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can group each stage with one or more jobs. You can easily retry jobs without having to run the whole stage. You will get the overhead of each job fetching sources or downloading artifacts and to use the output of a previous job you need to publish the result. One advantage is that jobs can run in parallel, your overall duration may actually be shorter that way.

Comment: sorry. can you specify more on the rerun part please? is it like I create one stage called 'Production' which has two jobs, job 1 includes task 1, job2 includes task2. I've only seen 'redeploy' option on my failed release pipeline to rerun the whole stage. Thanks

Comment: From the docs "You can now retry a pipeline stage when the execution fails. Any jobs that failed in the first attempt and those that depend transitively on those failed jobs are all re-attempted." the stage will resume from the last failed job when you retry a stage. So earlier jobs won't run again if they were successful.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/release-notes/2019/sprint-158-update?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5001511&#:~:text=You%20can%20now%20retry%20a%20pipeline%20stage%20when%20the%20execution%20fails.%20Any%20jobs%20that%20failed%20in%20the%20first%20attempt%20and%20those%20that%20depend%20transitively%20on%20those%20failed%20jobs%20are%20all%20re-attempted.

Comment: Thanks. Yes. I retried and found a redeployment option 'All jobs and deployment group targets that are either in failed, cancelled or skipped state'.